# Azure Queues: Delay between retries (Azure Function)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-queues

I'm using Azure Queues to save failed messages.

Each message have to be retried by an Azure Function 10 times before it is discarded.

How can I establish the delay between each retry? (if I use standard behaviour the message is retried 10 times in less than a second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question does not make it 100% clear if you are using queues in Azure Storage or Azure Service Bus. If you are using Azure Storage Queues:

You can leverage `visibilityTimeout` to configure the time between retries. Internally, this will lock the message to the current consumer for a specified amount of time. In case of error, the message will not be deleted and after the timeout Azure Queue makes the message available again to any available consumers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#host-json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
            "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
            "batchSize": 16,
            "maxDequeueCount": 5,
            "newBatchThreshold": 8,
            "messageEncoding": "base64"
        }
    }
}
```

> visibilityTimeout The time interval between retries when processing of a message fails.

See also this answer for some more details: [Azure function visibilityTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757623/azure-function-visibilitytimeout)

Comment: Thanks I was using Azure Service Bus. Now I understand the difference!

Answer (score 1):

That's a normal behavior for Azure Functions with Service Bus. If you need to have a delay between the retries, you'll need to implement a custom logic that either defers the original message and sends a scheduled message with the deferred original message's sequence number to retrieve it when the scheduled message appears on the queue and processed by the function. Or, alternatively, use a 3rd party library that supports this feature.

**Update**: as of version 5.14.0, `ServiceBusMessageActions` can be injected into the functions for message settlement operations. A bug with dead-lettering was fixed in 5.14.1

With this, you could build a backoff strategy to introduce delayed between retries rather than just having immediate retries as the number of deliveries.